# (Java) Receiving packets from the same socket on multiple threads simultaneously

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I'm writing a program that:

1. Sends ping packets to other processes running the same program
2. The process sends a response to the ping from (1)
3. If a process does not receive a response in X seconds, then call a method to update states

So I currently only have 1 `Datagram` socket that handles both sending and receiving the packets. The way I handled the ping timeout was calling `setSoTimeout` on the socket and blocking on the `receive` right after I send the ping packet to another process.

```java
public MyProgram {

    private DatagramSocket socket;

    public MyProgram() {

        socket = new DatagramSocket("localhost", 12345);

        Thread sendingThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // call sendLoop method
            }
        }
        Thread receiveThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // call receiveLoop method
            }
        }
    }

    public void sendLoop() {
        while (true) {

            /*
            send ping to other process
            */

            // now wait until it replies with ACK

            try {
                socket.receive(...);
            } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
                // call method to update state
            }
        }
    }

    // ... more code ...
}
```

Now the problem is when I write `receiveLoop` (separate thread to `sendLoop`) which waits for incoming ping packets from other processes

```java
public void receiveLoop() {
    while (true) {
        socket.receive(...);

        // call methods to reply to the ping
    }
}
```

How can I wait for a response to my own ping, whilst waiting for incoming pings on another thread? I figured this approach would be bad because the ping response could arrive on the other thread?
Can you even simultaneously call `receive` on the same UDP socket in different threads?

Is there a way to solve this without having to create another UDP socket? Many thanks!

Comment: You just need to have one thread that waits for any incoming messages. Have you ever tried to drink from a single hose with 5 of your friends at the same time? (For purposes of UDP, assume the hose provides a single drop of water every 5 seconds, for TCP imagine a regular hose).

Comment: @Kayaman How would I incorporate the timeout in this approach? Let's say I send a ping on the other thread and set a timer for X seconds, how would I communicate a receipt of a PING_ACK from the receiving thread to the sending thread?

Comment: Well the same way you do any inter-thread communication. Through some kind of shared element that both threads can access. BlockingQueues, semaphores and such are some possibilities. You might want to try a queue.